# How to interpolate scattered data on a predefined 3D surface in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, interpolation, surface

I need to interpolate scattered data on a model represented by a 3D surface in Matlab. I tried it using "scatteredInterpolant", but the results were quite bad. This function only allows to specify the query points but not the 'ConnectivityList' because internally it performs its own Delaunay triangulation from the specified point set. However, I perfectly know not only the points but also the 'ConnectivityList', so I can create a Matlab 'triangulation representation' using "triangulation".

So my question is the following. Is there any way to give a predefined 'triangulation' to "scatteredInterpolant"? If it is not possible, is there any other Maltab function or class able to perform data interpolation on a previously triangulated 3D surface instead of performing its own triangulation from the query points?